# What literary device is being used here?

Tags: literary-techniques, language-formation, figurative

> The beginning of prehistoric wars is a disputed issue between anthropologists and historians.

Source: http://ask.yahoo.com/20070404.html

I was reading that article and I noticed that sentence and it made me laugh for a moment. Is that a specific literary device being used there? Or is it just coincidence that it sounds weird and cool at the same time? It's like the sentence has meaning on two levels; the reals wars fought and the ones the historians are having over the real wars. I hope you guys understand what I'm saying.

Comment: This might not be a good example of the literary device you're thinking of. After all, *the beginning* (of the wars) is what is in dispute, not *the wars*. This is almost certainly a coincidence. But I think there may be a literary device you're thinking of, which is poorly illustrated by the example you've given, but of which you might be able to devise a better example.

Comment: Is this like the _black lady's purse_? Is the purse black, or does it belong to a black lady?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's a form of [mimesis](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=mimesis&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=wArPToW-Mc_U8QP79dwD&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=36b952feb5bfbbc9&biw=1137&bih=830), [defined by Wikipedia as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimesis)

> a critical and philosophical term that carries a wide range of meanings, which include: imitation, representation, mimicry, imitatio, nonsensuous similarity, the act of resembling, etc., etc...

I don't disagree with @Eliah Kagan's comment, to the effect that actually it's largely just *coincidence* that anthropologists and historians happen to be (metaphorically) "at war" over *how/when prehistoric wars started*. Arguably from that point of view, OP's example could be called [surreal](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=surreal&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=BxDPTpvLNIWf8gP9uezsCQ&sqi=2&ved=0CCUQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=36b952feb5bfbbc9&biw=1137&bih=830) *(bizarre, characterized by fantastic imagery and incongruous juxtapositions
)*.

Comment: Thanks. i think incongruous juxtapositions is probably the best way to describe that sentence.